# Remainder of $7^{220}$ when divided by $8$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How can I find out what is the remainder when I divide $7^{220}$ by $8$ using modular arithmetic and without using any theorems such as Fermat's Little Theorem or Chinese Remainder Theorem?

Comment: Any odd square is congruent to $1$ modulo $8$.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint.** $7\equiv -1 \pmod 8$, and $220$ is even ...

Comment: Thank you! 7 is -1 (mod 8), so 7^220 is (-1)^220 (mod 8), which means 7^220 is 1 (mod 8) and therefore the remainder is one!

Comment: @user265554: Exactly!